# Microsoft edge could not save picture as

Tags: microsoft-edge

When I open Microsoft edge and right click on a picture--> save picture as-->I got " Web browser could not save picture as". I have tried to reinstall Microsoft edge, change sign in to local account, scan antivirus, repair windows but it is still the same problem. My windows 10 version 1511.

Comment: This is a programming site. Try looking on Super User. I'd delete this question and post over there if you don't find an answer there

Comment: I could not find the something related my issue there, so please put my question over there... best regards

Comment: Go to http://superuser.com/ and join like you did here. Delete this question and post it over there. Btw ... you could check if you have corrupted files at http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/using-system-file-checker-in-windows-10